# React: CSS works in production, but not locally

Tags: css, reactjs

After running NPM Run Deploy, the app works on GH pages (https://github.com/mallen13/StarWarsPeople), but not locally w/ NPM start. This only happened after building the app.

Occasionally I get a console error that says: ' Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/index.css" '

I've tried renaming the CSS file. When I update the CSS file, CRA doesn't re-compile. It's like it doesn't even acknowledge the CSS exists.

Comment: App is for learning purposes and very early stages. Will look better later on.

Comment: What do you get if you open [http://localhost:3000/index.css](http://localhost:3000/index.css) directly in your browser? Might not be what you expect.

Comment: It goes right to an un-styled version of the app  for some reason. Tried multiple browsers/ cleared data.

Comment: Did you eject from create-react-app?

Comment: What this sounds like to me is your server is set up to return the html page for any and every path. So requesting `index.css` or `bananas.txt` or anything else will always get you the html. Some single page apps do this to allow bookmarkable routes, etc.. I don't know why running a build would change anything, but you might need to configure something to allow for [static file requests](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/) at particular paths or directories.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by importing my css through index.js rather than linking to it through index.html

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. Had to import my css through index.js module, rather than link to it through index.html.